# VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST on create acceleration structure and possible ways to debug it

Tags: c++, vulkan, raytracing

i'm trying to make a ray tracer in vulkan, so i need to make an acceleration structure. i've seen similar questions and understood that the VK_ERROR_DEVCE_LOST shows up on calling `vkQueueWaitIdle` when something is wrong with creating the acceleration structure, but i can't figure out what am i doing wrong, validation layers don't help either. the error occurs when creating bottom level acceleration structure. i'm trying to create it like this

```
    VkAccelerationStructureGeometryTrianglesDataKHR geometryData = {};
    geometryData.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_GEOMETRY_TRIANGLES_DATA_KHR;
    geometryData.vertexFormat = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;

    VkBufferDeviceAddressInfo bufferAddressInfo = {};
    bufferAddressInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_INFO;
    bufferAddressInfo.buffer = vertexBuffer;
    
    geometryData.vertexData.deviceAddress = vkGetBufferDeviceAddress(device, &bufferAddressInfo);
    geometryData.maxVertex = vertices.size()-1;
    geometryData.vertexStride = 0;
    geometryData.indexType = VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32;

    bufferAddressInfo.buffer = indexBuffer;
    geometryData.indexData.deviceAddress = vkGetBufferDeviceAddress(device, &bufferAddressInfo);

    VkAccelerationStructureGeometryKHR accelGeometry = {};
    accelGeometry.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_GEOMETRY_KHR;
    accelGeometry.geometryType = VK_GEOMETRY_TYPE_TRIANGLES_KHR;
    accelGeometry.geometry.triangles = geometryData;
    accelGeometry.flags = VK_GEOMETRY_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;

    VkAccelerationStructureBuildRangeInfoKHR offset;
    offset.firstVertex = 0;
    offset.primitiveCount = vertices.size() / 3;
    offset.primitiveOffset = 0;
    offset.transformOffset = 0;

    VkAccelerationStructureBuildGeometryInfoKHR accelGeometryBuild = {};
    accelGeometryBuild.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_GEOMETRY_INFO_KHR;
    accelGeometryBuild.type = VK_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BOTTOM_LEVEL_KHR;
    accelGeometryBuild.flags = VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_PREFER_FAST_TRACE_BIT_KHR;
    accelGeometryBuild.mode = VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_MODE_BUILD_KHR;
    accelGeometryBuild.geometryCount = 1;
    accelGeometryBuild.pGeometries = &accelGeometry;

    VkAccelerationStructureBuildSizesInfoKHR accelSize;
    accelSize.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_SIZES_INFO_KHR;
    vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR(device, VK_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_TYPE_DEVICE_KHR, &accelGeometryBuild, &offset.primitiveCount, &accelSize);

    VkBuffer scratchBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory scratchBufferMemory;
    createBuffer(accelSize.buildScratchSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_SHADER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, scratchBuffer, scratchBufferMemory);

    VkAccelerationStructureCreateInfoKHR accelCreateInfo = {};
    accelCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    accelCreateInfo.type = VK_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BOTTOM_LEVEL_KHR;
    accelCreateInfo.size = accelSize.accelerationStructureSize;

    createBuffer(accelCreateInfo.size, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_STORAGE_BIT_KHR | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_SHADER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, blAccelStructureBuffer, blAccelStructureBufferMemory);

    accelCreateInfo.buffer = blAccelStructureBuffer;

    if (vkCreateAccelerationStructureKHR(device, &accelCreateInfo, nullptr, &blAccelStructure) != VK_SUCCESS)
        log_fatal(std::runtime_error("failed to create a bottom level acceleration structure"));

    accelGeometryBuild.dstAccelerationStructure = blAccelStructure;

    bufferAddressInfo.buffer = scratchBuffer;
    accelGeometryBuild.scratchData.deviceAddress = vkGetBufferDeviceAddress(device, &bufferAddressInfo);

    VkCommandBuffer cmdBuffer = getSingleTimeCmdBuffer();

    std::array<VkAccelerationStructureBuildRangeInfoKHR*, 1> offsets = {&offset};

    vkCmdBuildAccelerationStructuresKHR(cmdBuffer, 1, &accelGeometryBuild, offsets.data());

    submitSingleTimeCmdBuffer(cmdBuffer);

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, scratchBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, scratchBufferMemory, nullptr);
}
```

In submitSingleTimeCmdBuffer there's a call to vkQueueWaitIdle which returns VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST. `vertexBuffer` and `indexBuffer` were both working fine with regilar graphics pipeline in the same code before adding acceleration structure building, also both of them contain `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_INPUT_READ_ONLY_BIT_KHR | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_SHADER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT` flags. `vertices` is a vector of `glm::vec3` which is used to create `vertexBuffer` object. `createBuffer` function is an abstraction to create a VkBuffer with corresponding VkDeviceMemory of given size with given usage flags and memory properties.

Also by any chance, is there any way to debug this? validation layers don't say anything useful there.

Comment: What do validation layers say? You said " [nothing] useful", what exactly does that mean? Also, at what level do you put the layers warnings? What layers do you use?

Comment: @Erel `nothing useful` is that it can't free the command buffer which is in pending state. that is caused by VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST, so i guess it don't actually point anything out there. i don't use the debug utils extension, the layers were always showing all validation errors fine (that extension can show some more information?). i'm using `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` validation layer

Comment: You could try the new [VK_NV_ray_tracing_validation](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_NV_ray_tracing_validation.html) extension. Not sure if NVidia has actually implemented it yet, but it's supposed to allow the ICD to send more detailed error messages that validation layers can't catch.

Comment: @vandench it seems that vulkan-headers don't have it yet

Comment: It just got added to the vulkan headers, like yesterday, release 1.3.280.0.

Comment: just tried to add it, my gpu (gtx 1070) don't support it from what i see, but maybe i just need to wait for the driver update

Comment: i got the driver update and no new extensions...

Comment: @vandench new beta driver got the extension, but when i enable it, there's no trace. i'm enabling it in device extensions, enabled a device feature, also set the environment variable `NV_ALLOW_RAYTRACING_VALIDATION=1` what should i also do?